# Error while trying to use pyramid_webassets and pyramid_jinja2 together

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid, webassets

I am trying to get my pyramid app to use [pyramid_jinja2](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/) and [pyramid_webassets](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_webassets).

My main config function looks a little like this:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.', encoding='utf-8')
    get_root = appmaker(engine)
    session_factory = session_factory_from_settings(settings)
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=get_root)
    config.include('pyramid_handlers')
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.add_jinja2_renderer('.html')
    config.add_jinja2_search_path('myapp:templates', name='.html')
    config.include('pyramid_webassets')
    config.add_jinja2_extension('webassets.ext.jinja2.AssetsExtension')
    assets_env = config.get_webassets_env()
    jinja2_env = config.get_jinja2_environment()
    jinja2_env.assets_environment = assets_env
```

After going through the docs multiple times it seems to be configured correctly but I keep getting the error:

```
jinja2_env.assets_environment = assets_env
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'assets_environment'
```

Not sure as to why `jinja2_env` is remaining undefined. The only dependency should be `pyramid_jinja2` which is definitely being used and set on the config object. Any insights or examples to configs with jinja2 and webassets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my question - https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/issues/111

needed a `config.commit()` in there.